# Rails Sprockets: require different JavaScript based on variable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Imagine I have a Rails application that can have multiple themes which  require different JavaScript per theme + JavaScript shared between themes.

The theme is specified as an ENV variable.

How could I require a different JavaScript file based on the theme?

I would like to do something similar to this in my `application.js` file:

```
/* Theme specific */    
//= require_tree "./theme/#{ENV[APP_THEME]}"

/* Shared between all themes */
(function() { ... })();
```

Which obviously doesn't work.
Does someone have an idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application.js is run once and done (when your application "compiles", so to speak). As long as it's spun up, no changes to that variable will have effect, as it will all have already been precompiled into a single javascript file based upon the value of ENV[APP_THEME] at launch. For this reason, logic in application.js is almost definitely not the proper solution to your problem.

The way to accomplish this is actually to exclude your theme-specific javascript from application.js entirely. Then, in your layout (presumably layouts/application.html.erb) user ENV[APP_THEME] to include the appropriate javascripts.

Comment: Oh well I see. I should create one application.<theme>.js per theme and require everything in there (application-wide and theme-specific JS) ;)

Comment: Essentially yes, that is true. The important part is that the logic which determines the theme lives in a location that is compiled whenever it is requested (likely in an .erb layout).

Comment: Just to add: it's also ok to have ruby code on `.js.erb` and `.css.erb`, just remember to add them like `config.assets.precompile += %w( foo.css.erb bar.js.erb )` in `config/environments/production.rb` so they are included in `assets:precompile`